# Flask @app.route('/hello/<name>') 404 Not Found

Tags: flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    return 'Hello %s!' % name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Did you enter `http://localhost:5000/hello/smit` in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Enter `http://localhost:5000/hello/<name>` route.

here, `name` parameter is taken value from the route.

i.e. `http://localhost:5000/hello/smit` and its return `Hello smit!`